# Angular 2 karma set up issue

Tags: unit-testing, angular, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

Hi I have configured the karma and jasmine for angular 2 unit testing but it is failing with 404 for one of angular 2 plug in which is present at specified location.

here is the folder structure:

[image]

And following is the error:

[image]

is there anything I am missing related to file path ?

Comment: Did you add the library to the `files` array in the `karma.conf.js` file?

Comment: Can you share more details about your test setup, like the karma config file?